# How to redirect in Django with form errors?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

In my project, I have an `order detail` page. This page has multiple forms (return order, deliver order etc.)

Each of this forms are handled using different views.

For example returning order form has action which calls `order_return` view which then, if `ReturnOrderForm` is valid, redirects back to `order_detail`.

The problem is when there are errors in the `ReturnOrderForm`. I would like to get back to `order_detail` and show the errors.

For now, I just render `order_detail` inside the `order_return` view in case there are errors, which works good but the url isn't changed to `order_detail` url. I would use `HttpResponseRedirect` but I have no idea how to handle errors.

Do you have any ideas?

```
def order_return(request):
    return_order_form = ReturnOrderForm(request.POST or None)
    order_id = request.POST.get('order_id')
    order = Job.objects.get(id=order_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if return_order_form.is_valid():
            ...
            order.delivery.return_delivery(notes=customer_notes)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("order_detail", args=(order_id,)))

    return render(request, "ordersapp/order_detail/order-detail.html",
                  context={'return_order_form': return_order_form,
                           ...})
```

Comment: Did you end up using the suggested answer, or did you do something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a shared method that can return the detail response

```
def get_order_detail_response(request, contxt=None, **kwargs)
     context = contxt or {}
     context['return_order_form'] = kwargs.get('return_form', ReturnOrderForm())
     return render(request, 'template', context)
```

Each view will then be able to return this

```
return get_order_detail_response(request, return_form=return_order_form)
```

Comment: Also note: the if statement checking the request method isn't required in your code since `is_valid` will never succeed without valid post data

Comment: I've got the same issue where one form posts to a view in a different app. But I am not able to find a way to return to the form if any errors are raised. Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see how this answers the question of the url being returned. It seems that the end result is no different than what they were doing to begin with. Where the 'order_detail' template is still being rendered under the url for the 'order_return' view.